# How to relate Async HttpWebRequest and some CallBack functions? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, visual-studio, delegates, httpwebrequest

For the getting data asynchronously,
I wrote Async Httpwebrequest functions in a common VB Module, and I wrote a getting HTML function in more than 3 Forms.

In the module:

```
Private Sub GetRequestStreamCallback(ByVal asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult) 
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(asynchronousResult.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)

    Dim postStream As Stream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult)
    Dim postData As String = <<<<<POST STRING DATA HERE>>>>>
    Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)

    postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, postData.Length)
    postStream.Close()

    Dim result As IAsyncResult = CType(request.BeginGetResponse(AddressOf GetResponseCallback, request),  _
        IAsyncResult)
End Sub

Private Sub GetResponseCallback(ByVal asynchronousResult As IAsyncResult) 
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(asynchronousResult.AsyncState, HttpWebRequest)
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult), HttpWebResponse)

    Dim streamResponse As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    Dim streamRead As New StreamReader(streamResponse)
    Dim responseString As String = streamRead.ReadToEnd()

    <<<<RETURING THE RECEIVED DATA TO THE FORM WHICH CALLED GETTING HTML FUNC.>>>>

    streamResponse.Close()
    streamRead.Close()

    response.Close()

End Sub

Public Sub GetHTMLAsync(ByVal POSTDATA as String,  <<<<FUNCTION ADDRESS OR SUCH THING TO CALL WHEN THE ASYNC PROCEDURE IS DONE>>>>)

    Req = CType(WebRequest.Create("http://hi.asdf.com/getinformation.php"), HttpWebRequest)
    Req.Method = "POST"
    Req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"
    Req.CookieContainer = CookieC
    Req.Timeout = 1000 * 30

    <DO SOMETHING TO DELIVER [POSTDATA] AND ["FUNCTION" ARGUMENT] TO ASYNC PROCEDURE ABOVE>

    'Async
    Dim result As IAsyncResult = CType(Req.BeginGetRequestStream(AddressOf GetRequestStreamCallback, Req), IAsyncResult)

End Sub
```

In the form:

```
Private Sub btnGet_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGet.Click

  GetHTMLAsync("name=klados&data=birthday", <<<getDataDoneCallBack something..>>>)

End Sub


Public Sub getDataDoneCallBack(ByVal text as String)

  'Show the received data(string)

  Msgbox(text)

End Sub
```

So, when I call the GetHTMLAsync, it hand over POST STRING to the async webrequest function in a module, and when the receiving the response data is done, it calls CallBack function in a Form.

Here, I just want to know 
1. How to hand over POST STRING to the GetRequestStreamCallback function?
2. How to call back the function in a certain Form from GetResponseCallback in the module?

Because btnGet(calling "GetHTMLAsync" function) buttons are existing in a few Forms, not a single one, the POST DATA and CALL BACK function should not be tangled or crossed.

I really appreciate for the answer. Have a good day!

## **QUESTION IN SUMMARY**

My question is simple. with the .Net Framework 3.5 (no Await function), I want to make two or more functions(Subs) containing independent Async Httpwebrequests in one Form.vb(or module, class). Thank you!

Call getHTML(address,parameter,callback_function)

=> gets info from ADDRESS with PARAMETER

=> if it gets data, it calls CALLBACK_FUNCTION

calling getHTML can be simultaneous that

> getHTML("http://a.com","name=hi",FUNCTION1)
>
> getHTML("http://b.com","day=happy",FUNCTION2)

should be working separately and independently that the receivedData should not be combined..

IF THAT IS SOMEWHAT DIFFICULT,
different getHTML functions with different callback functions in the same Form is okay too!

> getHTML_a("a.com",...) => call back gotHTML_a
>
> getHTML_b("b.com",...) => call back gotHTML_b

in the same Form.vb or Module.vb is also great!

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a good use for separate [BackgroundWorkers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.90%29).  Each BackgroundWorker uses it's own thread to perform tasks independent of each other.  You can pass you data once the BackgroundWorker is finished by using the [RunWorkerCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted%28v=vs.90%29) event.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will be a lot simpler if you used lambda expressions instead of plain functions for callbacks. This way, you'll "capture" the state you need to pass around. Here's a simplified sample of what your code could look like instead (VB.NET is not a familiar language to me, so apologies if there are syntax problems):

```
Public Sub GetHTMLAsync(ByVal postData as String, callback as Action(Of String))

    'Req = ...

    Req.BeginGetRequestStream( _
        Sub (asynchronousResult1)
            Dim postStream As Stream = Req.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult1)
            Dim byteArray As Byte() = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData)
            postStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
            '...
            Req.BeginGetResponse( _
                Sub (asynchronousResult2)
                    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Req.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult2)
                    Dim streamResponse As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
                    Dim streamRead As New StreamReader(streamResponse)
                    Dim responseString As String = streamRead.ReadToEnd()

                    callback(responseString)

                    '...
                End Sub, Req)
        End Sub, Req)    
End Sub
```

Notice how by defining a `Sub` *inline* like this, that I have access to variables outside of its scope. This is called a closure. So the callback for `BeginGetRequestStream` is able to "see" `postData`, and the callback for `BeginGetResponse` is able to "see" `callback` so it can call it.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't get into `Sub (asynchronousResult2)`. The outer function (BeginGetRequestStream) works fine while Req.BeginGetResponse doesn't...

Comment: Did you close `postStream` before calling `BeginGetResponse`?